# Suitable panel data method for regression

Tags: panel-data, group-differences

I am working on a project where I want to predict the GPA of students in the $k$th semester based on their GPAs in the last $(k-1)$ semesters. I have a data of 200 students from 2 batches of a 6 semester course--

1. Batch of 2020- I have the data for the first 5 semesters, as they have not yet taken the 6th semester test
2. Batch of 2021- I have the data of 3 semesters, they have not yet taken the 4th semester test.

I seek to do the following things--

1. Try to make a model to predict the GPA in the $k$th semester based on the GPAs of the students of the previous $k-1$ (or lesser number of) semesters.
2. The 3rd semester data of the batch of 2021 is dubious due to some reasons, can I use the data of the batch of 2020 (or any other method or way) to comment something on this, whether the distribution of the GPAs of 3rd semester for the batch of 2021 are actually statistically unusual? Because informal observation has shown some students of the 2021 batch who scored quite low in semesters 1 and 2 scored quite well in semester 3, and others who scored well on semesters 1 and 2 scored quite low in semester 3. 
   But that is informal, I want to know if is is possible to test that in a formal statistical way.

I have a satisfactory grasp of mathematics, but I am new to statistics, have dealt mostly with cross-sectional data so far.

What tools or methods can I use to meet the objectives mentioned above?

I am willing to learn new techniques to do the analyses.

Comment: I am also aware of informal data relating to student's GPA at the college level which recently saw a switch to more web-based learning and assignments based grading.  My speculation is that some students do better in the web environment.  My suggestion for testing is add (to the time series model) a new variable. Try a constructed dummy variable based on the difference between their high school GPA and the student's first semester grades in college, as this may reflect an impact from more teacher/student interactive high school learning environment to more self-learning expected in college.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, that would be an interesting topic too. But in my data-set, the dubious 3rd semester tests were taken before the coronavirus issue. The first objective does indeed relate to assignment based grading, but their scores have not yet been released. The second objective- of the dubious scores, is where exams were taken normally before the lockdown, but the evaluation was perhaps done in a hurry (just a guess), causing the strange GPAs.